# Restrict user input in the linux console

Tags: linux, bash

I need to restrict user input to the console. The limitation will be based on the hostname of the Linux server. For example, a user tries to login to some system from the RHEL server: login api.my-server.com. If the hostname of the server is my-server, than the login attempt is successful, otherwise the login attempt should be failed and accompanied by an error message.

Comment: So you want to say that you require to create a policy based on source IP/hostname? This is stupid but anyway, if you use SSH then see *AllowUsers* option in `man sshd_config`. IP is too dynamic, can be spoof to be source of trust.

Comment: There is nothing about SSH in the question. I am not sure what OP means by "console" and what the code snippet `login api.my-server.com` is supposed to mean. The [login command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) takes a user name as optional argument, but not a server name. Perhaps the question should be rewritten with correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)

**debian install:**
sudo apt-get install denyhosts -y

**centos install:**
sudo yum install denyhosts   #you will need to set up epel repo for your version of centos

Once installed, in your hosts.allow, you can whitelist those logging in with the domain you need it restricted to

**Add this entry to /etc/hosts.allow:**

`sshd : .my-server.com`

Comment: @Alex Lynch did it work out for you?